# JQuery preventDefault is refreshing page & displaying JSON as an array - how to get this data back into the same form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a Flask App that takes data from SQL, jsonifys it and when submitted returns a JSON array.

```
{"DoorType":"33PAL","FifthWheelHeight":"1000","FrontTensioner":"R61","NeckDepth":"158","POD":"No","RearPillarCodeNS":"N/S-Variable-R100-No-N/A-CS3/FS1/FS2-No-N/A-Barn or Flush Doors","RearPillarNS":"4RB-1385","RearPillarOS":"4RB-1386","RearTensioner":"R100","StrapStorage":"No","Wraps":"No","myList":[3583,3960,3960,3983,3990,4000,4001,4006,4030,4118,4120,4160,4160,4170,4170,4178,4183,4190,4200,4218,4228,4230,4240,4260,4285,4310,4333,4360,4360,4370,4380,4380,4383,4385,4410,4410,4415,4435,4440,4440,4450,4458,4460,4460,4470,4483,4485,4510,4518,4530,4530,4560,4560,4583,4590,4603,4610,4620,4660,4708]}
```

My issue is, I have js in my HTML page that is supposed to prevent my page from reloading and give me that JSON information back into my select tags, but the page reloads and gives me that array.

**My question is, how do I stop it reloading the page, and get that array transformed back into the selects. The reason for this, is the form needs to be posted for my `<select>{% for elem in myList%} <option> {{elem}} </option> {% endfor %}</select>` to be populated (as this takes data based on inputs and SQL and does a calculation to arrive at a list that can be put into this tag.**

My html page is as as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>CS3 Curtainsider Dimensions</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js " type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>CS3 Curtainsider Dimensions</h1>
</div>

<form method="POST">
<fieldset>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label for="DoorType"> Door Type</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="DoorType" id="DoorType">
      <option value="33PAL">33PAL</option>
      <option value="34PAL">34PAL</option>
  </select>
        <label for="RearTensioner"> Rear Curtain Tensioner</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="RearTensioner">
      <option value="R100">R100</option>
      <option value="R52">R52</option>
      <option value="R44">R44</option>
  </select>
        <label for="FrontTensioner"> Front Curtain Tensioner</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="FrontTensioner">
      <option value="R61">R61</option>
      <option value="R33">R33</option>
  </select>
        <label for="StrapStorage"> Strap Storage Required</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="StrapStorage" id="StrapStorage">
      <option value="No">No</option>
      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    </select>
        <label for="POD"> POD Required</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="POD">
      <option value="No">No</option>
      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    </select>
        <label for="Wraps"> Curtain Wraps Required</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="Wraps">
      <option value="No">No</option>
      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    </select>
        <label for="FifthWheelHeight"> Fifth Wheel Height</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="FifthWheelHeight" id="FifthWheelHeight">
      <option value="1000">1000</option>
      <option value="1200">1200</option>
      <option value="1250">1250</option>
      <option value="1300">1300</option>
    </select>
    <label for="Neck Depth"> Neck Depth</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="NeckDepth" id="NeckDepth">
      <option value="158">158</option>
      <option value="160">160</option>
      <option value="163">163</option>

    </select>

    <select class="form-control" name="option[2]" id="option[2]">
    <option value="115">Standard Cantrail</option>
    <option value="80">Slimline Cantrail</option>
</select>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate Available Overall Heights" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="button" name="button">
    <br>
    </div>
<div id="response">
    <select>
    {% for elem in myList%}
        <option> {{elem}} </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

</div>

</fieldset>
</form>


<script>

$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/Dimensions',
      data: $('form').serialize(),
      datatype: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function (response) {
    $('#response').empty()
        $.each(response[0], function (i) {
            $('#response').append($('<div>').append(
                //standard columns for all trailers
                $('<div>').text(response[0][i].FifthWheelHeight)))
        })
      }
})


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My python app is below: (note config is a file that just contains my classes and connection details)

```
from config import *

@app.route('/Dimensions', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Dimensions():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        DoorType = request.form['DoorType']
        RearTensioner = request.form['RearTensioner']
        FrontTensioner = request.form['FrontTensioner']
        POD = request.form['POD']
        Wraps = request.form['Wraps']
        NeckDepth = request.form['NeckDepth']
        FifthWheelHeight = request.form['FifthWheelHeight']
        StrapStorage = request.form['StrapStorage']

        RearPillarCodeNS = 'N/S-Variable-' + RearTensioner + '-No-N/A-' + 'CS3/FS1/FS2-No-N/A-Barn or Flush Doors'
        RearPillarCodeOS = 'O/S-Variable-' + RearTensioner + '-No-N/A-' + 'CS3/FS1/FS2-No-N/A-Barn or Flush Doors'

        RearPillarNS = db_session3.query(ConfiguratorRearPillar.PartNumber) \
            .filter(cast(ConfiguratorRearPillar.Code, VARCHAR).like(f'%{RearPillarCodeNS}%')) \
            .all()[0][0]
        RearPillarOS = db_session3.query(ConfiguratorRearPillar.PartNumber) \
            .filter(cast(ConfiguratorRearPillar.Code, VARCHAR).like(f'%{RearPillarCodeOS}%')) \
            .all()[0][0]

        LISTOFLENGTHSONLY = db_session2.execute('ConfiguratorRearPillarLengthsOnly :p1',
                                                {'p1': RearPillarNS}).fetchall()
        L2 = []
        for item in LISTOFLENGTHSONLY:
            L2.append(int(item[0]))

        AvailableOverallHeights = list(map(lambda x: x+int(NeckDepth)+int(FifthWheelHeight), L2))

        return jsonify(DoorType=DoorType, RearTensioner=RearTensioner,
                               StrapStorage=StrapStorage, FrontTensioner=FrontTensioner, POD=POD, Wraps=Wraps,
                               NeckDepth=NeckDepth, FifthWheelHeight=FifthWheelHeight,
                               RearPillarCodeNS=RearPillarCodeNS, RearPillarNS=RearPillarNS,
                               RearPillarOS=RearPillarOS, myList=AvailableOverallHeights)
    else:

        return render_template('Dimensions.html')
```

As always, any assistance will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your submit handler should definitely work. As I understand it, you have to take the `myList` from the json response and add it to the form to be further manipulated. Also, the other parameters can change, so you have to update the form selections too. I think this should work:

```js
// Simplified response
var response = {
  "DoorType": "34PAL",
  "FifthWheelHeight": "1000",
  "StrapStorage": "No",
  "Wraps": "No",
  "myList": [3583, 3960, 4590, 4603, 4610, 4620, 4660, 4708]
};

$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
  $targetElement = $('#response')
  if ($targetElement.children().length == 0) {
    // There's no select element
    event.preventDefault();

    // Perform ajax call
    // FAKE AJAX CALL
    console.log("Sending data: " + $(this).serialize());
    // Success handler
    for (key in response) {
      if (key == 'myList') {
        // Add the new elements from 'myList' to the form
        $targetElement.empty();
        select = $('<select></select>');
        response[key].forEach(function(item) {
          select.append($('<option>').text(item));
        })

        $targetElement.html(select);
      } else {
        // Update existing controls to those of the response. 
        // You can check if value has changed beforehand.
        $(':input[name="' + key + '"]').val(response[key]);
      }
    }

    // End handler
  }
  // Proceed with normal submission or new ajax call
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js " type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>CS3 Curtainsider Dimensions</h1>
  </div>

  <form method="POST">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label for="DoorType"> Door Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="DoorType" id="DoorType">
          <option value="33PAL">33PAL</option>
          <option value="34PAL">34PAL</option>
        </select>

        <!-- Elements omitted -->

        <input type="submit" value="Calculate Available Overall Heights" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="button" name="button">
        <br>
      </div>

      <div id="response">
        <!-- Empty element until form submitted-->
      </div>

    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response!

The section `var response = {
  "DoorType": "33PAL",
  "FifthWheelHeight": "1000",
  "StrapStorage": "No",
  "Wraps": "No",
  "myList": [3583, 3960, 4590, 4603, 4610, 4620, 4660, 4708]
};`
My issue is these values get changed on post, especially the myList variable, this will be populated on post, how would I get these to format into my page correctly?

Comment: @Nareik ok, the updated answer also updates the values for the other form elements.

Comment: Hi sorry I probably should have been clearer. What I need is the selected option to be what is in here:
`var response = {
  "DoorType": *****This bit should be what has been selected from the dropdown*******,`

This is because in my python code, the values that get inputted into the myList are based on calculations done by request.form['DoorType'] etc. So to get the correct values it needs to read what the user has selected.

Comment: @Nareik That variable is a **mock response** for the ajax call, since I can't really do an ajax call. I removed your ajax code altogether, but you should add it back. In there you were serializing the form correctly so you will be **sending** the actual values from the form. From the last comment I got that the server *might* change them, that's why I'm updating them. Added a couple lines where the real call should go.

Comment: Hi,

Sorry, just noticed that this works a treat the first time the submit button is pressed, but then if it's pressed again (say they change their mind about one of the options) it refreshes the page and displays the array again.

Any ideas?

Comment: That was intended behaviour, I assumed that the `myList` select was mandatory, so the ajax submission is only done if the `#response` element is empty and then you would submit the form normally for it to be saved, how would you know that they "are done editing" otherwise ? You can remove the `children().length == 0` condition to always submit it via ajax or add another submission method after the `if`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `type="button"` instead `type="submit"`.